# Concise way to do multiple interface conversions in Golang?

Tags: go, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to parse function calls from a code using `go/ast` package.

To do that, I first find all function calls like:

```
ast.Inspect(f, func(n ast.Node) bool {
    switch x := n.(type) {
    case *ast.FuncDecl:
        processFunction(x)
    }
    return true
})
```

And then, processFunction() looks like this:

```
func processFunction(e *ast.FuncDecl) {
    // Save wrapper function name
    f := e.Name.Name

    for _, expression := range e.Body.List {
        logrus.Printf("Current stmt: %#v", expression)
        pkg := expression.(*ast.ExprStmt).X.(*ast.CallExpr).Fun.(*ast.SelectorExpr).X.(*ast.Ident).Name
        fn := expression.(*ast.ExprStmt).X.(*ast.CallExpr).Fun.(*ast.SelectorExpr).Sel.Name
        fcall := fmt.Sprintf("%s.%s", pkg, fn)
        logrus.Printf("Yay. found my function call: ", fcall)
    }

}
```

The problem with this code is that if that particular hierarchy is not found in AST, the program panics. I know that we can do interface conversions gracefully via

```
x, ok := x.(type)
```

But, if I do each conversion like this, my code will be huge. Trying to use that in this fails of course.

```
    pkg, ok := expression.(*ast.ExprStmt).X.(*ast.CallExpr).Fun.(*ast.SelectorExpr).X.(*ast.Ident).Name
    if !ok {
        continue
    }
```

Error:

```
./parser.go:41: assignment count mismatch: 2 = 1
```

Is there a concise way to do these series of conversions and also fail gracefully if this hierarchy is not found?

Comment: That's one of those cases when using monads is practical (not to simply look cool): implement an `Either` monad and your expression would convert to `pkg := Either.Of(expression).Bind(GetExpStmt).Bind(GetX).Bind(...)`. It would return the value that either what you want or an error/null/a structure with additional data, that you can handle gracefully.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way, that I know of, to chain *type assertions*. But you can simplify this specific example by extracting duplicate code into its own function.

```
func fnSelExpr(s ast.Stmt) (*ast.SelectorExpr, bool) {
    if xs, ok := s.(*ast.ExprStmt); ok {
        if cx, ok := xs.X.(*ast.CallExpr); ok {
            return cx.Fun.(*ast.SelectorExpr)
        }
    }
    return nil, false
}
```

Then you can simplify your `processFunction` like this.

```
func processFunction(e *ast.FuncDecl) {
    // Save wrapper function name
    f := e.Name.Name

    for _, expression := range e.Body.List {
        logrus.Printf("Current stmt: %#v", expression)

        sx, ok := fnSelExpr(expression)
        if !ok {
            continue
        }

        var pkg string
        if id, ok := sx.X.(*ast.Ident); ok {
            pkg = id.Name
        }
        fn := sx.Sel.Name

        fcall := fmt.Sprintf("%s.%s", pkg, fn)
        logrus.Printf("Yay. found my function call: ", fcall)
    }
}
```